# Rest deployment Error

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, eclipse-plugin, tomcat7

I have created rest service using eclipse luna,tomcat 7 and jersy 1.8. I am getting null pointer exception. I have seen other posts but i couldnt solve my problem.

My rest service is.

```
@Path("/client")
public class client {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String sayHelloXML() { 
InstallationServiceImpl imp = new InstallationServiceImpl();
Installation inst=new Installation();
inst=  imp.getInstallation(1);
System.out.println("op is"+inst.getNumberOfAdults());
return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<msg>" + "Hello World in REST" + </msg>";
}
}

@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Installation getInstallation(int id) {
System.out.println("getInstallation 1 called");
Installation i1= new Installation();
i1= installationDAO.getInstallation(id);
return i1;
}

public Installation getInstallation(int installationId) {
System.out.println("getinstall 2 called");
return (Installation) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Installation   i 


where i.id = ?").setInteger(0,  installationId ).uniqueResult();
}
protected Session getCurrentSession() {
System.out.println("get Currentsession is called and session is " +   

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession());
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

I am getting following exception:

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing    

to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am getting exception at this line

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Installation getInstallation(int id) {
System.out.println("getInstallation 1 called");
Installation i1= new Installation();
```

I am getting null pointer exception at this line

```
i1= installationDAO.getInstallation(id);


SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Phoenix] in context with path      

[/Phoenix] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is   

java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at 
  com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.flex.service.HomeViewServiceImpl.getUserSummary(HomeViewServiceImpl.java:270)
at com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.flex.service.HomeViewServiceImpl.getUserSummary(HomeViewServiceImpl.java:261)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy36.getUserSummary(Unknown Source)
at com.hp.hpl.ress.phoenix.web.PhoenixController.homeSummary(PhoenixController.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

HomeController:

```
public UserVO getUserSummary(int userId, String startDateString, int rangeType, String resourceType) {
        logger.info("Into getUserSummary(" + userId + ", " + startDateString + ", " + rangeType + ", " + resourceType + ")");
        FlexSession userSession = FlexContext.getFlexSession();
        System.out.println("userSession is"+userSession);
        Long adjustmentMinutes = (Long)      

        userSession.getAttribute("adjustmentMinutes");
        int valueToAdd = 0;
        if (adjustmentMinutes != null) {
            valueToAdd = adjustmentMinutes.intValue();
        }
   270 LINE
   FlexSession userSession = FlexContext.getFlexSession();
    System.out.println("userSession is"+userSession);
```

Comment: Please add the full Exception. And format the code.

Comment: Looks like `installationDAO` is null. Where is it inizialized?

Comment: its iniialized by getters in another class and i have added the whole comment.

Comment: Please show the code of `HomeViewServiceImpl.java` and mark 270

Comment: I am sorry its too big ang body limit is only 300 letters hence i am not ale to post that code

Comment: Then add the Code arraound line 270.

Comment: public UserVO getUserSummary(int userId, String startDateString, int rangeType, String resourceType) {
        logger.info("Into getUserSummary(" + userId + ", " + startDateString + ", " + rangeType + ", " + resourceType + ")");
        FlexSession userSession = FlexContext.getFlexSession();
        System.out.println("userSession is"+userSession);
        Long adjustmentMinutes = (Long) userSession.getAttribute("adjustmentMinutes");
        int valueToAdd = 0;
        if (adjustmentMinutes != null) {
            valueToAdd = adjustmentMinutes.intValue();
        }

Comment: Please add it to your Question using the edit button.

Comment: And wich line is line 270?

Comment: i have added line no 270. please do check